# drag-drop group of events connected together in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, scheduler

i've a sequence of events connected together in FullCalendar + Scheduler, with this code:

```
resourceGroupField: 'building',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', building: 'Impianto 1', title: 'Cliente Pippo' },
            { id: 'b', building: 'Impianto 2', title: 'Cliente Pluto' },
            { id: 'c', building: 'Impianto 3', title: 'Cliente Pallino' }
        ],
        events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T02:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', title: 'Carico su camion', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false },
            { id: '2', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', title: 'Viaggio', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "red" },
            { id: '3', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', title: 'Scarico', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "grey" },
            { id: '4', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', title: 'Produzione', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "orange" },
            { id: '5', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', title: 'Pulizia impianto', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "blue" },
            { id: '6', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', title: 'Smontaggio', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "green" },
            { id: '7', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', end: '2017-09-08T06:00:00', title: 'Ritorno in azienda', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "pink" }
        ]
```

I need a simple code that when I drag-drop an event (for example event with ID = 1...the first), all the events connected together (using array: id_evento_collegato) follow the event dragged at the same time...so all the events have to set the new start and end time. I don't want to drag all the 7 events manually...but i need to drag 1 event and all remaining events follow the event dragged.

In attachment the example.

[IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/ranggi.jpg [/IMG]

Can anyone help me to do this?

UPDATE after help of @ADyson:

I tried to remove EDITABLE: FALSE to all events. if i move ALWAYS the same event (for example event 2) all is ok. But if i move an event (example event 2) and then I try to move another event (example event 4)...the "even-chain" broke.
Firebug get an error on:

```
for (var i = 0; i < event.id_evento_collegato.length; i++)
```

With error:

```
TypeError: event.id_evento_collegato is undefined
```

My updated code:

```
events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T02:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', title: 'Carico su camion', id_evento_collegato: [2,3,4,5,6,7] },
            { id: '2', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', title: 'Viaggio', id_evento_collegato: [1,3,4,5,6,7], backgroundColor: "red" },
            { id: '3', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', title: 'Scarico', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,4,5,6,7], backgroundColor: "grey" },
            { id: '4', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', title: 'Produzione', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,5,6,7], backgroundColor: "orange" },
            { id: '5', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', title: 'Pulizia impianto', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,6,7], backgroundColor: "blue" },
            { id: '6', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', title: 'Smontaggio', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,7],  backgroundColor: "green" },
            { id: '7', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', end: '2017-09-08T06:00:00', title: 'Ritorno in azienda', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6], backgroundColor: "pink" }
        ],
        eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            var newResourceId = event.resourceId;
            var relatedEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", function(evt) {
                for (var i = 0; i < event.id_evento_collegato.length; i++)
                {
                    if (evt.id == event.id_evento_collegato[i]) return true;
                }

                return false;
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < relatedEvents.length; i++)
            {
                relatedEvents[i].resourceId = newResourceId;
                relatedEvents[i].start.add(delta);
                relatedEvents[i].end.add(delta);
            }

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvents", relatedEvents);
        }
```

UPDATE 2: After some checks, i tried to add an alert here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < relatedEvents.length; i++)
            {
                relatedEvents[i].resourceId = newResourceId;
                relatedEvents[i].start.add(delta);
                relatedEvents[i].end.add(delta);
                alert(relatedEvents[i].id_evento_collegato);
            }
```

Basically "relatedEvents[i].id_evento_collegato" set to UNDEFINED after the first move...

UPDATE 3: Solved changing brakets in array [2,3,4,5,6,7] with "2,3,4,5,6,7" but i still don't undestand why

Comment: you mean you want to automatically move all the events associated with a given resource, if any single event from that resource is moved? And they should all have the same start/end time as the event dragged originally? Even though they don't have that now? You'll need to be a bit clearer about the requirements.

Comment: Hi, all events (connected together via "id_evento_collegato" array ) have to modify their new position. For example...if i drag-drop event with ID = 1 to new time start: 2017-09-07T01:00:00.... (so... 1 hour earlier)...all event have to decrement their start and time of 1 hour. I'd like to manage all 7 events like one single events during drag-drop

Comment: it would make more sense if each instance of id_evento_collegato did not contain the ID of the event it is contained within (e.g. for event ID 1, it would have `id_evento_collegato: [2,3,4,5,6,7]` without the 1. And for event ID 2 it would be `id_evento_collegato: [1,3,4,5,6,7]` etc). But otherwise I think I understand. Let me see if I can create a solution.

Comment: yes you're right about ID of the contained within... but i use it for a "for cycle" if i need to delete a event...all the events related will be deleted.

Comment: you still don't need it for that, because you can delete the selected event anyway using its ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you need. It is based on what I suggested, where the id_evento_collegato list does not contain the ID of the event it is within.

Note I removed `editable: false` from the first event, to allow it to be dragged. If you want to allow this functionality to work with any of the events, then remove that property from all of them.

Note also that it only works for dragging, not resizing. If you need that as well, please let me know.

It works quite simply by using fullCalendar's "clientEvents" method, with a filter, to return the event objects for all the related event IDs. Then it uses the `delta` property included in the eventDrop callback, which is a Duration indicating the amount of time by which the event was moved, to update the start and end times of all the related events by the same amount. Finally "updateEvents" is called to change the events on the calendar itself.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'YourLicenseKey',
    defaultDate: '2017-09-07',
    scrollTime: "00:00:00",
    editable: true,
    header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek,timelineMonth,timelineYear'
    },
    defaultView: "timelineDay",
    resourceGroupField: 'building',
    resources: [
        { id: 'a', building: 'Impianto 1', title: 'Cliente Pippo' },
        { id: 'b', building: 'Impianto 2', title: 'Cliente Pluto' },
        { id: 'c', building: 'Impianto 3', title: 'Cliente Pallino' }
    ],
    events: [
        { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T02:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', title: 'Carico su camion', id_evento_collegato: [2,3,4,5,6,7] },
        { id: '2', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T04:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', title: 'Viaggio', id_evento_collegato: [1,3,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "red" },
        { id: '3', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T13:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', title: 'Scarico', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,4,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "grey" },
        { id: '4', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T15:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', title: 'Produzione', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,5,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "orange" },
        { id: '5', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T19:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', title: 'Pulizia impianto', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,6,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "blue" },
        { id: '6', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T21:00:00', end: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', title: 'Smontaggio', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,7], editable: false, backgroundColor: "green" },
        { id: '7', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-09-07T22:00:00', end: '2017-09-08T06:00:00', title: 'Ritorno in azienda', id_evento_collegato: [1,2,3,4,5,6], editable: false, backgroundColor: "pink" }
    ],
    eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
        var relatedEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", function(evt) {
            for (var i = 0; i < event.id_evento_collegato.length; i++)
            {
                if (evt.id == event.id_evento_collegato[i]) return true;
            }

            return false;
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < relatedEvents.length; i++)
        {
            relatedEvents[i].start.add(delta);
            relatedEvents[i].end.add(delta);
        }

        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvents", relatedEvents);
    }
});
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/ for more details of the eventDrop callback, which runs when an event has finished being dragged.

Comment: It work perfectly!!! Thanks. If i need to drag-drop another event (not 1...but...for example n. 3) and enable EDITABLE on all events, the code is more difficult?

Comment: No problem. Once I looked at the eventDrop callback, and realised it included the `delta` variable, the logic was quite simple.

Comment: Probably i need in the future to able to resize a event...so the events AFTER the event resized need to be modified in start and end time :)

Comment: well, actually only the end time would need to be changed for a resize...you can't modify the start time by doing that. Modifying the start time can only be done via dragging. But basically you can reproduce almost the same code above, but using the eventResize callback: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventResize/ . You just need to ignore the start time. Probably you can in fact create one separate function to share the code, passing in only the event and delta parameters, and execute that from both the eventResize and eventDrop callbacks.

Comment: i've a little problem. i tried to remove EDITABLE: FALSE to all events. if i move ALWAYS the same event (for example event 2) all is ok. But if i move an event (example event 2) then i try to move another event (example event 4)...the "even-chain" broke... i can't tell me why...

Comment: Just tried it myself, no problem at all. I can move any of the events I like, as many times as I like, and they always update properly. Strange. Perhaps you changed something else as well as that?

Comment: firebug report this error if i move another event ID: for (var i = 0; i < event.id_evento_collegato.length; i++).       TypeError: event.id_evento_collegato is undefined

Comment: well that can't be true, unless you forgot to define it on one of your events. If you're using event data different to above, or you modified those events, double-check what they look like.

Comment: i've checked but i don't know why... i posted my upd code.

Comment: I've run your updated code, moving every different event around, and I don't get that error at all. Whatever you're doing, that code is not the problem.

Comment: Update 2: i set an alert inside the FOR loop and I found the problem...but i can't understard your run is ok..

Comment: I've solved changing array [2,3,4,5,6,7] with "2,3,4,5,6,7" . Do you know why?

Comment: no, that makes no sense to me whatsoever, and I can't reproduce the problem. Sorry.